# change background color by iterating through array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a container with a light blue background on my page and I would like for the background to get sequentially darker with each click. At this point, I'm happily setting my array of colors manually (we'll leave that question for another day) but I'm unable to get the background color to change or iterate over the array like I would like.

Currently, I'm getting alerts that there was an error in parsing my background color. I've tried setting background-color for .content in the css document and removing it, but neither way works (except if I remove it, then there's no background color at all)

Here's a rough sense of the code I have so far. I built it based on this jsfiddle from another thread, though it does not match entirely: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3eGM5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var blues = ['#c4c4fd', '#5d5dbc'],
    counter = 0;

$(".content").click(function() {

    $(".content").animate({
        backgroundColor: blues[counter++]});


#the text in this div also changes on click, so here's my animation for that. 
#This is working fine, but I figured I'd include it just to be safe


    var current = $('.active');
        var next = current.next('.section');

        if(next.length === 0) {
            next = $('.section').first();
        };

        current.fadeOut(400).removeClass('active');
        next.delay(100).fadeIn(1500).addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Is there an obvious solution to this that I'm missing? I'm still pretty new to jQuery and putting everything together, so any advice or any direction you can point me in would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the code you're currently using is the code from above you're missing an opening ' in front of your second color in your array. This would cause a syntax error when the code is run. What does your markup look like that corresponds exactly with the code above?

Comment: Also you can't animate a background color with jquery without the jquery color plugin. [Check out the docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties)

Comment: so I got the jquery color plugin (thank you!) and it works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox I get the error "$.Color is not a function" I've done some googling but no dice. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your color isn't being animated because you need to use the [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to animate colors.

So you'd need to include the jquery color plugin in your markup and then change your animate code to look similar to this.

```
$("#block").animate({
        backgroundColor: $.Color(blues[counter++])
}, 1500 );
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you! The only concern is it works fine in Chrome, but when I run it in Firefox (latest), it gives me the error "TypeError: $.Color is not a function"

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer? Also that "TypeError" could be because the plugin isn't instantiated properly. Where did you include the script? Can you access it in the javascript console by using $.Color() or jQuery.Color()? Are you using a document ready function. The shorthand for jquery is $(function(){ //all of your code goes here  });

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's on ready [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) if you're confused about the shorthand.

Comment: accepted! I tried including the color script both in the header (after loaded jquery ui) and before the closing body tag, but neither made a difference. It works fine in Chrome though, just firefox is throwing the error. They're both included in a document ready function. Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: Where is the jQuery script included in your markup. In the head? What order are the scripts instantiated? I saw you said after jquery ui, this is a jquery plugin it needs to be loaded after jquery, it extends jquery so the jquery object needs to be defined before the plugin is instantiated.

Comment: I have it after both jquery and jquery ui (last in the list of jquerys in my head) and before my script.js. i tried moving it before the closing body tag but still got the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69694/discussion-between-doug-wallace-and-tuck).